# AzCopy login fails

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, storage, azcopy

After running `azcopy login` and signing in with my Azure account, I see the following response on the sign in page:

“User account  from identity provider  does not exist in tenant ‘Microsoft’ and cannot access the application  in that tenant. This account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign back in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.”

Am I missing something like an App Registration?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are probably facing this issue because you are not specifying your Azure AD tenant-id while trying to login with `azcopy.exe`

So instead of

```
azcopy.exe -login
```

You should do

```
azcopy.exe -login --tenant-id=yourtenantid
```

- When you don't specify any tenant-id it tries to login to "Microsoft.com" tenant, where obviously your specific Azure AD user like `kyle@myaad.onmicrosoft.com` doesn't exist and hence the error.
- If you don't know your Azure AD Tenant Id already, one of the many ways to find it is by going to Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > Your specific Azure AD > Properties (The Guid in Directory ID field is your Azure AD Tenant ID)

  [image]
- On a side note, I was able to reproduce your issue doing exactly just the login without my tenant mentioned and then able to successfully login by specifying the tenantid appropriately.

  Issue using only `azcopy.exe login`
  [image]

  Successful login using `azcopy.exe login --tenant-id=fa89xxxxxxxx`
  [image]

Comment: The syntax for this command has changed slightly to: AzCopy login /tenant:tenant-id-goes-here

Comment: @daveywc thanks for that information. I'll check and update the answer as well a little later.. for anyone referring to it in future.

Comment: On OS X, the syntax in the answer worked for me (and it is what the info message recommends as of Jun 2020).  i..e, `azcopy login --tenant-id=<your-tenant-id>`.  Also be aware that nothing seems to change on the command line but when you open the browser you no longer get the error message.

Comment: Using existing tenant id simply worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: To add, if you're getting 403 while uploading after login, simply generarte SAS and append that to the destination URL to upload files.

Answer (score -1):

You need to sign in with an MSA account that is already part of an Azure Tenant

Comment: When I attempt to login, I am using an account that is associated with an Azure Tenant. In other words, the account I am attempting to login with is controlled via Azure Active Directory. Could you elaborate if you meant something else?